# Apply image to label

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to apply an image to this label. But it dosen't show anything. 
I tried following the instructions on http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm but without success.

```
class App(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        photo = PhotoImage(file="screeniess.png")
        w = Label(self.frame, image=photo)
        w.photo = photo
        w.pack()

root = Tk()
root.title("Application")
root.geometry("400x500")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using `.png` file. From the [PhotoImage class](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) page of effbot.

> The PhotoImage class can read GIF and PGM/PPM images from files:
>
> ```
> photo = PhotoImage(file="image.gif")
>
> photo = PhotoImage(file="lenna.pgm")
> ```

In same page:

> If you need to work with other file formats, the [Python Imaging
>   Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) contains classes that lets you load images in over 30
>   formats, and convert them to Tkinter-compatible image objects:
>
> ```
> from PIL import Image, ImageTk
>
> image = Image.open("lenna.jpg")
> photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
> ```

Comment: Thanks for that :)